# How to fetch SQL data using api and use that data in react-native-svg charts? I am having an API that I want to use to fetch data and display

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, react-native, svg

I am fetching some data using an api. Inside that api there are SQL queries that are executed. I have api that will be used to fetch data or execute these queries. I want to know how can I replace my chart's static data with dynamic data that will be fetched from api.

Here is my `TabDashboardDetail.js` where I am fetching title for all charts based on api data:

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultScrollView from '../components/default/DefaultScrollView';
import ChartView from '../components/default/ChartView';
import CogniAreaChart from '../components/CogniAreaChart';
import { areaChartData } from '../chartData';

const TabDashboardDetail = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const tabsConfig = route.params.tabsConfig;
  return (
    <DefaultScrollView>
      {tabsConfig.components.map((comp, index) => {
        return (
          <ChartView key={index} title={comp.name}>
            <CogniAreaChart areaChartData={areaChartData} height={200} />
          </ChartView>
        );
      })}
    </DefaultScrollView>
  );
};

export default TabDashboardDetail;
```

Here is my `CogniAreaChart.js` which is chart file that is currently being rendered:

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { AreaChart, YAxis, XAxis } from 'react-native-svg-charts';
import * as shape from 'd3-shape';

const CogniAreaChart = ({ areaChartData, visibility, ...props }) => {
  const xAxis = areaChartData.message.map((item) => item[Object.keys(item)[0]]);
  const areaChartY1 = areaChartData.message.map(
    (item) => item[Object.keys(item)[1]],
  );

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: props.height,
        flexDirection: 'row',
      }}>
      <YAxis
        data={areaChartY1}
        contentInset={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
        svg={{
          fill: 'grey',
          fontSize: 12,
        }}
      />
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AreaChart
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={areaChartY1}
          contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
          curve={shape.curveNatural}
          svg={{ fill: 'rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.8)' }}
        />
        <XAxis
          style={{ height: 20 }}
          data={areaChartY1}
          formatLabel={(value, index) => xAxis[index]}
          contentInset={{ left: 30, right: 30 }}
          svg={{
            fill: 'grey',
            fontSize: 12,
            rotation: 35,
            originY: 5,
            y: 15,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CogniAreaChart;
```

Here is areachartData that is currently being used in `CogniAreaChart.js`:

```
export const areaChartData = {
  message: [
    {
      year: '2018',
      quantity: 241.01956823922,
      sales: 74834.12976954,
    },
    {
      year: '2019',
      quantity: 288.57247706422,
      sales: 80022.3050176429,
    },
  ],
  status: 'success',
};
```

I have the API that I will replace with the example if anyone suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign a state variable for data and make an API call on component mount and  save  that to state variable

[snack example with dummy data](https://snack.expo.io/@srinath116/svg-charts)

Comment: @ManishRana glad it hepled you